# How do i solve this "Notice: Undefined offset: on line 14"?

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could give me a little help I have a php script and its giving me this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in xxxx/xxxx/xx.php on line 14

here is the code I have:

```
     <?php  

    // Opens the file "april" in read mode only
    $fileLog = fopen("april.txt", "r");

    // Variable to count the total bytes used during the month
    $totalBytes = 0;

    // While not the end of file get and echo the data line by line
    while (!feof($fileLog)) {
    $line = fgets($fileLog, 1024);


    // Explodes the data with a space   
    $details = explode(' ', $line);

    // Adds all the bytes and stores them in $totalBytes
    $totalBytes = $totalBytes +(int)$details[8]; // line 14
    }
    echo "<h3>April Statistics</h3>";

    // echoes the total bytes
    echo "<p>The TOTAL bandwidth consumed used: 8.43MB ($totalBytes Bytes)</p>";
    fclose($fileLog);

    ?>
```

Can anyone tell me how do I solve this or give me an example.
Any help will be deeply appreciated thank you.

ok here is an example of the file's contents:

103.239.234.105 -- [2007-04-01 00:42:21] "GET articles/learn_PHP_basics HTTP/1.0" 200 12729 "Mozilla/4.0"

207.3.35.52 -- [2007-04-01 01:24:42] "GET index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 11411 "Mozilla/4.0"

and im adding the total bandwidth consumed by the file requested over the month.

Comment: You have at least one line that contains fewer than nine "words", which causes `$details` to have fewer than nine elements (offset 8 would be the ninth element).

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing what is on line 14 of your text file, it would appear that there are not 9 words separated by a space on that line.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is with the text file, without seeing it it will be difficult to help.

But, you could just print out to a file each line you process and see where it fails, or, better, is to put in some error handling, so you look for where there is not enough words, then print out some warning, or skip the line.

Comment: The PHP interpreter is talking about line 14 of his *source file*, not his text file.

Comment: @robjb - You are correct that the line 14 is in the source file, but still the problem lies in the datafile.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your `$details` variable has less than 9 elements in it. Therefore, when you try to access `$details[8]` that doesn't exist, and there's your error.

To fix it, I'd debug your other variables, specifically the `$line` variable. It looks like there's (at least) one line in the file you're opening which isn't in the format you're expecting. Note that this may well be an empty line at the end or something.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump` to show the contents of `$details`. You are getting the notice because the index 8 (which you are trying to access) is not set to any value.

Answer (score 1):

Well the $details array probably doesn't have 9 elements you could access.
Print the $details array to see what actually is inside it.

To fix the warning you should check if the $details array contains the data you expect before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$totalBytes = $totalBytes +(int)$details[8]
```

to

```
$totalBytes = $totalBytes +(isset($details[8])?intval($details[8]):0);
```

Comment: Be careful! This may not be the desired behaviour if the line has fewer than 9 "words"; e.g. it may be desirable to consider this an "error" case, rather than just assuming a value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the 14th row `$offset = count($details)-1;`

Comment: That just creates a variable. It doesn't fix the problem or change the meaning of the program.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to say that `$details[8]` needs to be renamed as `$details[$offset]`

Comment: Hi there Simone thank you for your reply, i did as you said and it worked the problem is that the $totalBytes result is now different(less than it was therefore is wrong) any suggestions???

Comment: what you are doing is to always get the last column.  If the last column is the one containing the size, then this is correct, else you risk to include strings into your total.  If you are looking ONLY for the 9th column, then use the `isset`